# Magento cronjobs

Tags: magento, cron

I have my Debian crontab working properly, as some scripts are periodically running with no problems, the problem comes when running the magento cron.php:

After following several docs, I've tried so far:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.sh


*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.php

*/5 * * * * curl -s -o /dev/null http://www.mysite.com/absolute/path/to/magento/cron.php
```

According to the Debian syslog, the file is being executed every 5 minutes, but nothing seems to happen, in our module (xtento extention), the declaration of the cronjob is correct:

```
 <crontab>
    <jobs>
        <export_apply_all>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>export/observer::cronjob</model>
            </run>
        </export_apply_all>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

This is a paid and stable extension, so I dont know why magento is not scheduling the tasks...the database table "cron_schedule", remains empty, nothing..not even the default clear logs task is being scheduled...any ideas what am I missing? any help is appreciated.

Comment: and what happens if you execute the cron.php directly from command line ? note that CLI must have all same modules/memory limits etc that magento requires

Comment: it runs with no errors...cron is being executed, from the command line, from the crontab, and even directly from the browser...but I think the problem lies within Magento, don't you think?

Comment: I have same problem, it looks like Magento not read <crontab> section in xmls at all

Comment: Something is missing on you model definition.
export - Namespace and observer is a class, you are missing your's module name. It should be like: `export/mymodule_observer::cronjob`

Answer (score 1):

As i am thinking cron.php is not working properly. Please open the cron.php file which is located under magento root. Then go to the line no 48 then you will see a variable by named $isShellDisabled . Please make this variable true always. Please add below line just above try block. Then hit cron.php again.

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
Mage::log('cron running');
```

to cron.php (around line 50) in the root of the site.

Then check your log file var/log/system.log to see if your Debian cron is indeed triggering your Magento cron.  If nothing is logged after 5/10 minutes then the problem lies in the Debian cron.

If nothing is logged then try downloading a fresh cron.php file for your version of Magento.